# Data not being displayed properly through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, highcharts

I'm currently trying to get a chart I have as drilldown remove all series data previously and redraw with new data. Below I've added the ajax calls and the html/javascript for the chart. The problem was that everytime I called the chart, it would rebuild the chart and double call. So I've been trying to get it to simply remove the data and redraw with new data from the ajax call.

AJAX & SetData call:

```
           self.drilldownLoad = (year: number) => {
            self.isDrilldownLoading(true);
            self.isDrilldownLoaded(false);

            $.ajax({
                xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                url: areaUrl + "api/Incident/IncidentDrilldown?year=" + year,
                success: data => {
                    self.isDrilldownLoading(false);
                    self.data(data);
                    self.setDrilldownPlotData(data);
                    self.isDrilldownLoaded(true);
                },
                error: data => {
                    self.loadingError(true)
                }
            });
        } 

        self.setDrilldownPlotData = (data: any) => {

            while (self.drilldownPlotData().length) {
                self.drilldownPlotData().pop();
            }

            while (self.drilldownPlotDataLabels().length) {
                self.drilldownPlotDataLabels().pop();
            }

            var len = data.List.length,
                i;

            var criticalData = [];

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                criticalData.push(
                    data.List[i].Critical 
                )
            }

            var highData = [];

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                highData.push(
                    data.List[i].High 
                )
            }

            var mediumData = [];

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                mediumData.push(
                    data.List[i].Medium 
                )
            }

            var lowData = [];

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                lowData.push(
                    data.List[i].Low 
                )
            }

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                self.drilldownPlotDataLabels.push(
                    data.List[i].IncidentMonth 
                )
            }

            self.drilldownPlotData.push(
                {
                    name: 'Critical',
                    data: criticalData,
                    color: '#fa5a5a',
                },
                {
                    name: 'High',
                    data: highData,
                    color: '#fea156',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Medium',
                    data: mediumData,
                    visible: false,
                    color: '#b191c3',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Low',
                    data: lowData,
                    visible: false,
                    color: '#83bfd1',
                }
            )
        }
```

This creates the initial chart. Once the chart is initialized, I set it to not be recreated every time I have data load from this particular ajax call. I can't seem to get it load the series data in correctly and redraw the chart.

```
 var = subchartCreated = false;

         viewModel.isDrilldownLoaded.subscribe(function () {
        if (!subchartCreated) {
            specificChart();
            subchartCreated = true;
        }
        if (subchartCreated === true)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < specificChart.series.length; i++) {
                specificChart.series[i].remove(true); //forces the chart to redraw
            }
        }
    });
```

I have two charts, one chart is the initial chart and that one is loading just fine. The second chart is the one of interest and I would like to have it load once and then simply load the series data, remove it from the second chart and then redraw with the new data. This is the click function that I have in the first chart to load the second chart. Currently, it works on the first load, but will not update data beyond that.

```
      point: {
           events: {
           click: function () {
                   viewModel.drilldownLoad(this.category);
                   $('#drilldownButton').removeClass('hidden');
                   $('#yearlyincident-container').addClass('hidden');
                   $('#drilldown-container').removeClass('hidden');
                   $('#incidentInfoGrid').addClass('hidden');
                   $('#incidentDrillDownGrid').removeClass('hidden');
                   getDrilldownData(this.category);
                  }
               }
            }
```

I feel like its a relatively easy fix, but I'm just not getting it right. My initial attempts only removed the click functionality of the first chart. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using drilldown.js module? I think it will give you exactly what you would like to achieve. Here you can see an example imitating ajax drilldown: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/
For removing charts you can use Series.remove(), for adding new series to chart you can use chart.addSeries(). You can also use Series.update() for giving your series new parameters (like new name or new data).

Comment: I am not using drilldown.js. I'd like to be able to use the 2 chart setup I've created for now. However, I will look into drilldown.js for the functionality.